# Can objects animated by the Animate Objects spell take psychic damage?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, damage-types, animated-objects

The [Animate Objects](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/animate-objects) spell description reads:

> An animated object is a construct with AC, hit points, attacks, Strength, and Dexterity determined by its size. Its Constitution is 10 and its Intelligence and Wisdom are 3, and its Charisma is 1. Its speed is 30 feet; if the object lacks legs or other appendages it can use for locomotion, it instead has a flying speed of 30 feet and can hover. If the object is securely attached to a surface or a larger object, such as a chain bolted to a wall, its speed is 0. It has blindsight with a radius of 30 feet and is blind beyond that distance. When the animated object drops to 0 hit points, it reverts to its original object form, and any remaining damage carries over to its original object form.

According to the description, it seems like objects animated by the Animate Object spell aren't immune to psychic or poison damage. This is in contrast to every other animated object in game, from [animated armors](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/animated-armor) to [tiny servants](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/tiny-servant) created by the [XGE spell](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/tiny-servant). Are objects animated by the Animate Objects spell an exception to general rule? Are they susceptible to poison and psychic damage, as well as conditions like charmed or frightened?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### They are not immune to psychic damage because they don't say they are.

In 5e, Psychic Damage is just a flavor of damage. Creatures are only immune/resistant to certain damage types if their stat block says they are.

Comment: And it is a creature because it has a creature type. JC has mentioned that quite a number of times, however never bothered to put something that important into Sage Advice or errata.

Comment: @Slagmoth I can't find evidence of JC ever saying that something is a creature because it has a creature type. Could you share your sources with us?

Comment: @GuillaumeF. I believe this was [one of the Tweets](https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/820091935868133376?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw%7Ctwcamp%5Etweetembed%7Ctwterm%5E820091935868133376%7Ctwgr%5Eb82f42ab923a712e5cae5c37757596a1eec3ac40%7Ctwcon%5Es1_&ref_url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.sageadvice.eu%2Fdoes-a-sentient-magic-item-count-as-a-creature%2F)I was referring to, it has been a while pretty sure there was one referring to undead or constructs as well. I will try to find it but it has been a couple of years.

Comment: @GuillaumeF. [This](https://www.sageadvice.eu/is-there-an-explicit-definition-of-creature-somewhere-in-5e-books/) sort of alludes to creatures having to have a type from the MM. There are a few others but I think you get the gist. Back when I commented on this JC's Tweets were "official" they aren't any longer though. By the spell granting a type it is no longer an object at least for the duration of the spell as far as I have read, there is some disagreement on that on this stack though. Your DM will have to make that final ruling.